# XCopy command not working in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I am trying to run a simple xcopy command at machine shutdown.
When I execute the command via cmd ,  everything works as expected.
However when I paste it in a batch file and try to run it , I encounter errors.
Here is the command:

```
FOR /D %d in (*) DO xcopy /S /I /y /exclude:exclude.txt %d V:\SUBFOLDER\%d
```

The error I get is : "unexpected exclude.txt "
I tried surrounding the file name with quote marks but it is didn't solve the issue. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a batch file, you need to use `%%d` rather than `%d`:

```
FOR /D %%d in (*) DO xcopy /S /I /y /exclude:exclude.txt %%d V:\SUBFOLDER\%%d
```

If you're serious about learning various Windows scripting tools, you can't go past [Rob van der Woude's website](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/). This covers a very wide range of subjects. You may also want to consider switching to Powershell since it's a great step up from the `cmd.exe` scripting language.

Comment: wow that was quick! Thanks a lot! Where can I find more infos about this?

Comment: @uaaron22, see the update for an excellent learning resource.